# Why does jQuery accept an array as argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code executes just fine :

```
$([ $('<div>'), $('<div>') ]);
```

and returns an array extended with jQuery properties (i.e. `each`, `find`, and all other `$.fn.*` functions).

However, it is neither a DOMElement or a function, therefore the object cannot be used for DOM manipulations.

Why does jQuery accept arrays as argument?

---

#### Edit (because it seems many don't get why I'm asking this)

```
var els = $([ $('<div>'), $('<div>') ]);

$('body').append( els );
// ERR : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

I am asking this question as this feature seems inconsistent with the rest of jQuery's API.

---

#### Update

It seems this [issue has been addressed](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9011) (thank you [@Stryner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367305/why-does-jquery-accept-an-array-as-argument#comment58441098_35367305) for finding this) a while back and decided to not implement this feature for obvious reasons (performance and WTF-prone).

Comment: [Because it does](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)? Why shouldn't it? An array of DOM elements is the natural representation of a collection, exactly what jQuery is working with everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, but nothing can be done with it afterwards :)

Comment: See [Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-elementArray)

Comment: As far as I know, [jQuery() always returns a `jQuery` object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: I've never noticed this feature, but like @Bergi says, it seems useful.

Comment: @YanickRochon You can call all the jQuery functions on it? I wouldn't call that "nothing".

Comment: I wouldn't call `.each()` nothing.

Comment: Damn, people are quick to judge!

Comment: Your example does not [pass an array of DOM elements](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-elementArray), but an array of jQuery objects.

Comment: As @Blazemonger says, you would need to use something like `var els = $([ $('<div>').get(0), $('<div>').get(0) ]);` to be able to append.

Comment: See, these two last comments have much sense than all others. Thank you, this makes much sense.

Comment: See https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9011

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation [shows it accepts an array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-elementArray) of elements.

```
var els = $([
   document.createElement("div"),
   document.createElement("div") 
]);

$('body').append( els );
```

… works fine.

Your particular example is failing because you aren't passing in an array of elements. It seems jQuery simply has (arguably) insufficient error checking.

Comment: Alright, I understand. And I also get the fact that it is the dev's responsibility to pass correct arguments. It simply didn't occur to me that this would be so, as all jQuery's manipulation functions does accept an array of jQuery objects. It's all good. :)